# Show only latest tweet and add links to results from JSON Array / Twitter Stream code

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, stream

I'm using this code to connect to Twitter Stream from client side (I need to stick to this method, please dont offer alternative ways) - and I am trying to understand how I can limit the outcome to only show one tweet (the latest one). Right now it shows all of the tweets from the result. I edited out the hashtag & username in the search URL just insert your own if anyone wants to help me. Here's the code:

```
<div id="tweet_stream">
Loading #Apple tweets...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
// Execute this code when the page is ready to work
// Create a Script Tag
 var script=document.createElement('script');
 script.type='text/javascript';
 script.src= "http://search.twitter.com/search.json? q=%23HASHTAGHERE+from:USERNAMEHEREr&callback=processTheseTweets&_="+ new Date().getTime();
 // Add the Script to the Body element, which will in turn load the script and run it.
 $("body").append(script);
 });

 function processTheseTweets(jsonData){
 var shtml = '';
 var results = jsonData.results;
  if(results){
 // if there are results (it should be an array), loop through it with a jQuery function
  $.each(results, function(index,value){
  shtml += "<p class='title'><span class='author'>" + value.from_user + "</span>: " +
  value.text + "<span class='date'>" + value.created_at + "</span></p>";
  });

 // Load the HTML in the #tweet_stream div
  $("#tweet_stream").html( shtml );
  }
 }
 </script>
```

I'm also trying to get the final outcome to show the HTML version of the tweet, so that links show up. Any help to do either of these things would be super great!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating html of each element of result array in $.each() and appending it in shtml variable. Instead of iterating over results, just find out index of latest tweet. It might be first element (index 0), last element (index results.length-1), or some other based on your logic.

```
var index = 0; //suppose its first element.
var value = results[index];
shtml = "<p class='title'><span class='author'>" + value.from_user + "</span>: " + value.text + "<span class='date'>" + value.created_at + "</span></p>";
$("#tweet_stream").html( shtml );
```

Now you have the html version of tweet. If you want to show, use text() instead of html().

```
$("#tweet_stream").text( shtml );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching all tweets and showing 1 tweet why dont you restrict api to give only 1 tweet ?

Change url to this,

```
script.src= "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23HASHTAGHERE+from:USERNAMEHEREr&callback=processTheseTweets&rpp=1&_="+ new Date().getTime();
```

i.e. set rpp (result per page) to 1